# C++ atof - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

I'm working on a simple C++ application, but this is the first time I'm using command line arguments.
It actually worked fine, until i added the option for the program to calculate more numbers than one at a time.

I use the following code to convert the argv to a float. (Well the code that's relevant in this case)

```
if (argc != 1)
    brugervinkel = atof(argv[1]);

if (argc = 3)
    brugervinkel2 = atof(argv[2]);
```

etc.

It worked as it should before i added the option to use more arguments at once.

Well now if i don't use all the argument's available i get the following error

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

That means if i type `./program number1 number2 number3` i get no errors
but if i type
`./program number1`
It still displays the correct result, but on the last line it adds the above mentioned error when executing the program.

How would i fix this? Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: `(argc = 3)`->`(argc == 3)`. Next time format your question properly

Comment: But anyway your conditions look fishy, maybe there are more problems elsewhere.

Comment: May I suggest reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `argc = 3` write `argc == 3`. Always be careful with assignment and equality check in C-style languages :)

Answer (score 0):

Jabberwocky's comment is actually the answer, I believe. I think the bug is that the questioner actually used `(argc = 3)` instead of `(argc == 3)`, and it's not just a formatting error in the question.

If you did use `(argc = 3)` then instead of testing argc you are actually setting argc to 3 **and** the assignment evaluates to true, so no matter what was the original value of `argc`, the code will execute `brugervinkel2 = atof(argv[2]);`. Then, of course, `./program number1` will crash, since you don't have enough arguments.

Comment: I feel very stupid, the problem was solved by adding an extra = which i forgot.

Comment: @Jesper -- don't feel stupid. It's an easy typo when you're getting started. After you've fixed it a hundred times or so it will turn up less and less often.